# Updating items inside a list in real time using the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my ViewModel there is an ObservableCollection, which is populated when the ViewModel loads.

```
public ObservableCollection<Price> ItemPrices
{
    get
    {
        return _itemPrices;
    }
    set
    {
        _itemPrices = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ItemPrices");
    }
}
```

This binds to a ListView which in turn contains a GridView for layout purposes. Among the items inside the GridView is a  Image:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemPrices}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>

            <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="auto">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.DocumentCommand}" >
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PriceDocumentImageConverter} }" />
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The Binding inside Source gives a clue as to what I'm wanting to do here: change the source of the Image depending on the state of one of the properties of the bound object. I need this to happen in real-time so, as the user changes the appropriate properties, the image changes accordingly.

When this screen first loads, it works as expected. I get the right image source depending on the state of the object. However, if I update the object via the UI, the image never changes - even though I can see the state of the object is changing in the database.

I am raising the appropriate OnPropertyChanged event for ItemPrices.

At first, I thought that using a Converter might be the wrong approach. So I swapped it for a Trigger instead:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Icons/Document-Add.png" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasDocument}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Icons/Document-View.png" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

But that doesn't work either.

So I figured I'd try refreshing the ObservableCollection after save, going back to the database to get a new set of the objects I'd just saved -  but that doesn't work either.

I've done things like this before, but in those instances I've been able to work with and update a single item in the collection - say a SelectedItem, for example because I want something to change when a user clicks on it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` already has `OnPropertyChanged` event trigger inside, you can remove it.

Comment: Does you HasDocument call OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: @adminSoftDK No - but I don't see how I can raise one. I guess that's part of the problem. It's a calculated property, dependent on whether a Price object has an attached Document object or not. But without having a single Price object on the ViewModel to raise the event, where do I send the notification?

Comment: You can still raise one for calculated property, when any of the other properties (which HasDocument is made off) changes call OnPropertyChanged("HasDocument") and it will raise it for that property. It should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @adminSoftDK Yeah, I'm not explaining myself very well. The objects themselves come straight from EF - they don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged. The ViewModels do, but the ViewModel only has the collection - it doesn't expose individual objects. So I'm not sure how/where to raise this event. That's kind of the question.

Comment: I see, there are couple of choices of which I know of in this case. You can wrapp your EF object with many properties on your viewmodel, each property would return EF property, but the UI will bind to the wrapper. Second option (my preffered one) is to create EntityViewModel, and then implement InotifyPropertyChanged on its properties, then use something like automapper to mapp the two entities. So in the second option you would end up with 2 classes for each entity, one which is only used to transfer the object and the other one which interacts with your views.

Comment: @adminSoftDK Rats. I had a nasty feeling it might come to something like that :( sledgehammers to crack a nut.

Comment: Having two types of entities is nothing bad in my opinion. It will allow you track state of the entity (whether is dirty or not), have a better validation, even do some logic inside them, like adding/removing children etc. It takes time to implement it, but once done it is a powerfull technique

Comment: @adminSoftDK Yes, I've done it before. But it's a lot of added overhead to solve a relatively simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using OnPropertyChanged() is good in that accessor for times when you need to replace the entire collection. It doesn't throw changes for properties changing however.

You will need to call OnPropertyChanged() on the property itself.

**Update:**

Also, Observable Collections only fire updates "when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I'd assumed. The question is: how. I don't have the individual objects showing through the viewmodel, only the collection.

Comment: It wouldn't be crazy to add OnPropertyChanged notification on that objects accessors. The notification should bubble up if done correctly.

Comment: @MattThrower In short, you usually never have a set accessor on your `ObservableCollection`s.  Someone may have already said it, but the items inside your collection need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`